# stop jQuery .animate delay - but .queue deletes all delays

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I want to position a div-container in the right bottom corner of the window. This div should only be visible when you scroll and additionally it should have a delay of some seconds. This works fine but I also wan't to have a close button. And the problem is, that the close button also has the delay but it shouldn't have it.

I've read that I have to use jquery .queue() but then it deletes all delays. As I'm new to JS, I don't know how to implement this correctly. I tried maaaany possibilities but nothing worked fine for me. Maybe someone could help me here. Thanks!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.quick-contact').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){


                $(this).delay( 1000 ).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
                $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},500);
            }

        }); 

    });

});
$(document).ready(function(c) {
    $('.alert-close').on('click', function(c){
        $('.quick-contact').fadeOut('fast', function(c){
            $('.quick-contact').remove();
        });
    }); 
});
```

http://codepen.io/p1x3lp4shr/pen/rxZpNN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run 53 times your `animate` function for only one `$('.quick-contact')`

I have add a variable `active = 1` for check is animated.

Please try, it's work fine

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var active = 1;
    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){
    
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.quick-contact').each( function(i){
            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object && active ==1){
                $(this).delay( 1000 ).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
                $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},500);
                active = 0;
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
    
});
$(document).ready(function(c) {
 $('.alert-close').on('click', function(c){
  $('.quick-contact').fadeOut('fast', function(c){
     $('.quick-contact').remove();
  });
 }); 
});
```

```css
.wrapper
{
  width:100%;
  height:1500px;
  position:relative;
}
.quick-contact
{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:200px;
  right:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background:#f6f6f6;
  color:#333333;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:99;
}
.alert-close
{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="quick-contact">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<div class="alert-close"><div class="close-btn">Close me</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwOedm

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll( function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $(".quick-contact").delay( 1000 ).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
        $(".quick-contact").animate({'bottom':'0px'},500);
      }
    });
    
});
$(document).ready(function(c) {
 $('.alert-close').on('click', function(c){
  $('.quick-contact').fadeOut('fast', function(c){
     $('.quick-contact').remove();
  });
 }); 
});
```

```css
.wrapper
{
  width:100%;
  height:1500px;
  position:relative;
}
.quick-contact
{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:200px;
  right:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background:#f6f6f6;
  color:#333333;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:99;
}
.alert-close
{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="quick-contact">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<div class="alert-close"><div class="close-btn">Close me</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh very nice - that works perfect for me! I understand now what the problem was. The each function is there because I've copied parts of the script from an other script where this function is needed and I didn't realize that it's here unnecessary. Could you tell me what should I write instead of "each"? Thank you very much!